# Encriptar informacion en MySql y desencriptar en php

Tags: php, mysql

Resulta que voy hacer un encriptacion masiva en Mysql creando una funcion de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE FUNCTION encryptData(dataInfo varchar(60), masterKey varchar(32))
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
BEGIN
   DECLARE result varchar(250);
   SET @@session.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-ecb';
    SET result = (select to_base64(aes_encrypt(dataInfo,MD5(masterKey))));
   RETURN result;
END;
```

y con esta función para desencriptar

```
CREATE FUNCTION decryptData(dataInfo varchar(60), masterKey varchar(32))
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
BEGIN
   DECLARE result varchar(250);
   SET @@session.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-ecb';
   SET result = (select (aes_decrypt(from_base64(dataInfo),MD5(masterKey))));
   RETURN result;
END;
```

Y deseo desencriptar la informacion con codigo Php nativo

¿Hay manera de emular la encriptacion de MySql en php o vicerversa?

Comment: en php existe la función password_hash que hace exactamente lo mismo que el encrypt de mysql, la diferencia es que en php no existe forma de obtener el string original (es decir desencriptar), lo que se usa es la función contraria que es password_verify, que compara el string de tu input actual con el que esta almacenado (en forma de hash) en tu base de datos y te regresa un valor booleano es decir falso o verdadero segun sea el caso. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Lo mejor es que  busques una manera de consumir tu funcion en MySQL desde tu aplicacion asi no duplicaras codigo y facilitas el mantenimiento.

Comment: mysql tiene la función encryptData que sirve para encriptar, en php existe la función password_hash que hace lo mismo, la diferencia radica en que mysql tambien tiene la función decryptData que te regresa el string original y php no tiene una función que desencripte el hash, en php existe la funcion password_verify que comparar un string con un hash(tu string encriptado) y te devuelve un valor booleano si son iguales y false si no lo son.
puedes ver este video si te quedan dudas https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfDI2V-Vaik